# Reference updated row for SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I want to always update the value of an update row in the database.

Imagine, i have a table with names and prices
Every time a row is inserted or updated, i want to lower the price by a fixed amount.

How can I do this with SQL server 2005?

I have now something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER LowerPriceOnInsert ON products
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(ProductPrice)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so let's say you wanted to reduce the price by 5 cents:

```
UPDATE p
  SET price = price - 0.05
  FROM dbo.Products AS p
  INNER JOIN inserted AS i
  ON p.ProductID = i.ProductID;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Comment: It works, however, i cannot change the values of the rows anymore. I get an error saying that: The row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multiple rows.

While i just alter the price of one row using management studio. Any idea?

Btw vote up for the answer anyway

Comment: I got it fixed by removing the IF UPDATE(ProductPrice). Thnx a lot!

Comment: Henri, it seems like you do not have a primary key on your table?  Can you show the actual code and table structure in the question, or start a new question?  Tough to debug commentary.  :-)